# How do you change each part of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So here is the code I have right now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int set[] = new int[5];
    set[0] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    set[1] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    set[2] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    set[3] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    set[4] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;

    System.out.println("Your current dice: " + set[0] + " " +  set[1] + " " + set[2] + " " + set[3] + " " +set[4] );
    System.out.println("Select a die to re-roll (-1 to keep remaining dice):");
    int ask = keyboard.nextInt();
```

After this if the user types in let's say 1 then `set[1]` should change to the number zero and so it becomes `x0xxx` and if the user also wants the 3rd number to change then it should be `x0x0x`.

The `x`'s are just the generated random numbers by the way.

How do I keep doing this? It has to be a total of utmost 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic steps you should follow to accomplish what you want/need.

1. Read user input (using `Scanner` or something else).
2. Validate if the user input is a valid index for the array (this is, the input is a number with a value between 0 and 5). You can store this in a variable `int x`.
3. Change the value of the element of the array inside the index user entered to 0 (or the value you want/need). This would traduce into something like `set[x] = ...` (change the `...` by the proper value).

Comment: How would this work for multiple times though. I can see it working once, but after I change the first int to 0 how do I change the other ones to 0 as well?

Comment: @WinterOne wrap this inside a loop like a `for`, a `while` or a `do-while`.

Comment: Here's what I have... but I don 't think this is going to work.                                                                                       
     http://pastebin.com/yv7KcZy1

Answer (score 0):

The way you do one thing many times is in a loop.  The key is in learning which kind of loop to use.

For things that get applied to every element, use a for-each loop.  For things that need done until some condition use a while loop.  For things that need done until some condition becomes false, use a do-until loop.

The thing you do is the same, that goes into the block of the loop.  The thing you are "working on" changes, that is a variable which the loop will set each time it "goes through" the loop's block.

In your case

```
for (Die die : dice) {
  die.roll();
}
```

where class Die looks like

```
public class Die {

  private int value;

  public Die() {
    roll();
  }

  public void roll() {
    value = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then, since you need "order" (first, second, third, etc...) use a data structure that can contain Objects (like your Die)

```
List<Die> dice = new ArrayList<>();
```

Arrays are nice, and you do need to know how to use them; however, there are far better ways of solving most problems by not using them.

When you really can't get around using them, use a for loop to walk each array index.